# Turn an image from grey to a real deep black when hovering

Tags: css

When I'm hovering the image I would like it to turn black. The image is gray by default.

[image]

```css
img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(1.6) saturate(2) contrast(150);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpQiz.png">
```

Comment: Well, first you click the 'edit' button and put the code you wrote in your attempt to solve it into your question. :)

Comment: I understand, sorry, it's done :)

Comment: You are trying to change the image color when you hover?

Comment: through filter yes it's my guess

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't change an image's color with CSS.  But I don't know a lot about 'filter', so maybe that is possible

Comment: can you share you real image, because a grey circle is easy to change

Comment: yep my real image are twitter and facebook icons, I put theses here

Comment: What is your image? A `.png`? An `.svg`? Something else? It makes a big difference. Please update your question to show a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: how about using `grayscale(100%)` instead of `greyscale(100%)`?

Comment: my images are png but I can get them as svg also is not a problem

Comment: @disinfor I have also used grayscale, that did'nt work so I have changed in greyscale

Comment: You're code above says `greyscale`. Fiddle with `grayscale` http://jsfiddle.net/2fwtu8aj/

Comment: I have a kind of grey flat image for basis so it brokes slightly the process, but work a few turning all value to 0

Comment: @disinfor yes I have errata my error

Answer (score 3):

Use the invert filter and you will get closer:

```css
img:hover {
 filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpQiz.png" >
```

Or simply `brightness(0)`

```css
img:hover {
 filter: brightness(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpQiz.png" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not think the other way around, use a black image and change the visual with `opacity` levels?

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}
img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo3De.png">
```

Comment: and of course we should pay attention to the background behind

Comment: Aha, good catch! It really depends on what the actual case is.

Answer (score 1):

Could not the following be done? (you would need 2 separate images though, one gray and one colored black)

```
<img src='../img/badge/graydot.png' onmouseover="this.src='../img/badge/blackdot-hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='../img/badge/graydot.png';" />
```